# Order of rules in makefile matters?

Tags: makefile, g++, rule

My `makefile` have two lines:

Rule_1

```
File.o : File.cpp
    g++ -c File.cpp -o File.o
```

Rule_2

```
File   : File.o
    g++    File.o   -o File
```

I want any change in `File.cpp` leads to regeneration of both `File.o` and `File`. This is done by:

`Makfile`:

```
Rule_2
Rule_1
```

But the following does not work and only regenerates `File.o`

```
Rule_1
Rule_2
```

Why? I note that, I am not using any `all:` in my makefile. With `all: File` both methods above work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your make tool is GNU Make.

Unless you specify targets on the commandline, like:

```
make File
```

`make` will by default attempt to make the first target
in the makefile, which in your problem case is `File.o`.
See [How make Processes a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile)

When you add:

```
all: File
```

at the top, `all` is the first target, which depends on `File`,
which in turn depends on `File.o`.

And I suggest you replace that with:

```
.PHONY: all

all: File
```

See [Phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)

Comment: Or if the OP (or anybody :) ) use FreeBSD's make can use the `.MAIN` target (see https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1) ).