# Writing compilation rule before linking rule in makefile doesn't produce executable

Tags: makefile, compilation, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

I am confused by an apparently simple problem related to makefiles. Consider the following makefile:

```
main.o: main.f95
    gfortran -c main.f95
run: main.o
    gfortran -o run main.o
```

Here, I am writing a compilation rule *before* the linking rule. However, this does not produce the executable `run`. If I change the order as:

```
run: main.o
    gfortran -o run main.o
main.o: main.f95
    gfortran -c main.f95
```

Then the executable `run` is produced! Searching on the Internet, I found some information that says that the actual order in which rules are arranged does not matter. See [this](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Eyzhou/computer/writemakefile.html) for example. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you call the Makefile? If you don't specify which rule to run, i.e. you call `make`, only the first rule encountered is executed - `main.o` in the first case, `run` in the second. For either case, if you explicitly call `make run`, you should get the expected result, regardless of the order the rules are defined in the Makefile itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of rules in makefile matters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795010/order-of-rules-in-makefile-matters)

Comment: @jbdv: Yes it does. However, the link I posted is ambiguous then since it says that the order doesn't matter which is not true.

Comment: The [GNU Make manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html) (emphasis mine): "_The order of rules is not significant, **except** for determining the default goal: the target for make to consider, if you do not otherwise specify one._" That's the complete & correct statement to relate to.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.